# qml Camera save same image with different resolutions

Tags: qt, camera, qml, resolution

I'm using QML's `Camera` component and `Camera.imageCapture` to save images.

I want to save multiple resolutions of the same image when user click "Capture" button.

The code I'm trying to run is simply like this:

```
// 160x120
camera.imageCapture.resolution = Qt.size(160,120)
camera.imageCapture.captureToLocation("/location/")

// 320x340
camera.imageCapture.resolution = Qt.size(320,240)
camera.imageCapture.captureToLocation("/anotherLocation/")

camera.imageCapture.resolution = Qt.size(-1,-1) // set to default again
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have solved:

1. Save the image with **highest resolution available** in Camera:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    camera.imageCapture.resolution = camera.imageCapture.supportedResolutions[camera.imageCapture.supportedResolutions.length-1]
}
```

2. Give the path of that file to the [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html)'s constructor.
3. Then scale & save:

---

Full Code:

imageresizer.cpp:

```
#include "imageresizer.h"
#include <QImage>
ImageResizer::ImageResizer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

void ImageResizer::resizeImage(int width, int height, QString file, QString savefile)
{
    QImage img(file);
    img = img.scaled(width, height);
    img.save(savefile);
}
```

imageresizer.h:

```
#ifndef IMAGERESIZER_H
#define IMAGERESIZER_H

#include <QObject>

class ImageResizer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImageResizer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
    void resizeImage(int width, int height, QString file, QString savefile);
};

#endif // IMAGERESIZER_H
```

Don't forget to make it available from QML:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qmlRegisterType<ImageResizer>("project.imageresizer", 1, 0, "ImageResizer"); // Here

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import project.imageresizer 1.0
Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    title: ""

    ImageResizer {
        id: imageResizer
    }

    // Use it like:
    // imageResizer.resizeImage(100,100,imgPath,scaleImgPath)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd save your camera input to a QImage you can save and resize and save again using QImage's image.save() and image.scaled() functions. 
I've used these functions before for resizing images and it works perfect.
However I don't know how you can save the camera input to a QImage, but I'll look into that and report back.

I know it's not a full answer to your question, but it's a start. I hope that this was helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I have managed to do that with QImage::scaled. Actually I'm looking for a `Camera` based solution but anyway.